# Dispelling more than one spell on a creature

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

One of my player cast Dispel Magic using 3rd spell slot on my NPC Wizard who has more than one spells in effect: Foresight, Mind Blank and Contingency (none of those spells requires concentration).

Does my player need to make a spellcasting ability check against each of those spells by casting a single Dispel Magic? Or must he cast Dispel Magic for each of them one by one?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You may want to take the [tour]. You have 2 really good questions here - to ensure that they both get answered properly, we prefer to have one question per post. I've edited out your second question, but I encourage you to make a new post asking it.

Comment: I aprreciate your help especially for correcting my grammar faults, and encouraging me to ask more questions. I think I'm gonna wear you guys down more :)

Comment: You're welcome! I look forward to seeing lots more questions!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Dispel Magic* says the following:

> Choose
>   one
>   creature,
>   object,
>   or
>   magical
>   effect
>   within
>   range.
>   Any
>   spell
>   of
>   3rd
>   level
>   or
>   lower
>   on
>   the
>   target
>   ends.
>   For
>   **each**
>   spell
>   of
>   4th
>   level
>   or
>   higher
>   on
>   the
>   target,
>   make
>   an
>   ability
>   check
>   using
>   your
>   spellcasting
>   ability.
>   The
>   DC
>   equals
>   10
>   +
>   the
>   spell’s
>   level.
>   On
>   a
>   successful
>   check,
>   the
>   spell
>   ends.

So your player can get all 3 spells with a single *Dispel Magic*, but he will have to make separate ability checks for each of them.

Comment: To go further, it's clear from the wording that you can choose to get just one of the three spells by targeting a "magical effect", *or* all three, by targeting a "creature". So, the player can choose to target just the *contingency*, for example, or they can target the wizard and end all spells on them.

Comment: @anaximander I'm not sure about that. The rule can be read as if you target a magical effect, the effect is dispelled, but if you target a creature, all spells affecting it are subject to be dispelled. It depends on the signification given to the word _any_.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that as worded, you could declare "I target the wizard's *contingency*" and specifically end that without affecting any other spells on them.